# How to create element onclick which removes the element's parent node?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to make a box copier that creates boxes which each contain a button to delete itself. Each box is a duplicate of a hidden template box, and each has an id starting at `box1`:

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
let boxcount = 0;

function removebox() {
    this.parentNode.remove();
}

function addbox() {
    var container = document.getElementById("container"),
        box = document.getElementById("boxoriginal");
    var boxcopy = box.cloneNode(true);
    
    boxcount += 1;
    boxcopy.id = "box" + boxcount;
    container.appendChild(boxcopy);
    
    var remover = document.createElement("DIV");
    remover.innerHTML = "x";
    remover.onclick = removebox;
    document.getElementById(boxid).appendChild(remover);
}
```

The problem is that if I click on the X in `box1` for instance, it removes the last box just added, rather than `box1`. I've tried something similar using EventListener but with the same result.

I'm brand new to JS, so I can only guess that I'm misunderstanding how `this` works.

Comment: Please create a [mre] (using the `<>` button) also, what is `boxid`?

Comment: Here's a fixed version: https://jsfiddle.net/g3mnvx8j/

Comment: That is because you are not decrementing upon removal like `function removebox() {
    this.parentNode.remove(); boxcount--;
}`, not that I recommend using an id to get a dynamic Element. The Element is already `boxcopy`, so you don't have to get it again, just use that variable and get rid of doing your ids like that and get rid of `boxcount`.

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @SlackSlave Thanks for the suggestion, got rid of the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a perfect solution for what you are trying to achieve, but you might want to create a structure more like:

```js
let doc, bod, M, I, SimpleBoxMaker; // for use on other loads
addEventListener('load', ()=>{
doc = document; bod = doc.body; M = tag=>doc.createElement(tag); I = id=>doc.getElementById(id);
SimpleBoxMaker = function(appendTo = bod){
  this.container = M('div');
  this.addBox = contentNode=>{
    const container = this.container, box = M('div'), x_div = M('div');
    box.className = 'box_div'; x_div.className = 'x_div'; x_div.innerHTML = '&times;';
    box.appendChild(x_div); 
    if(contentNode)box.appendChild(contentNode);
    x_div.onclick = ()=>{
      box.remove();
    }
    container.appendChild(box);
    return this;
  }
  appendTo.appendChild(this.container);
}
// below code can be put on a separate page using a `load` Event (besides // end load line)
const bigBox = new SimpleBoxMaker, addBox = I('add_box');
addBox.onclick = ()=>{
  const div = M('div');
  div.textContent = 'Before adding this node there were '+bigBox.container.children.length+' children in the container';
  bigBox.addBox(div);
}
}); // end load
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box:
}
.box_div{
  min-height:30px; border:1px solid #000; margin-top:2px;
}
.x_div{
  cursor:pointer; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; width:30px; height:30px; background:#900; color:#fff; font:bold 24px san-serif; text-align:center; float:right;
}
```

```html
<button id='add_box'>Add Box</div>
```